# clearInterval on one node while timer continues on another

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a slideshow driven by switching classes only. All transitions are in the CSS. Multiple instances may be on the page. How can I stop the one that is clicked while the others continue?

clearInterval() seems to stop all instances.

```js
var slideshows = document.querySelectorAll('.slideshow');
function startSlideshow() {
    return window.setInterval(function(){
        for (var i=0;i<slideshows.length;i++){
            var $this = slideshows[i];
            var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.current');
            for (var i=0;i<slides.length;i++){
                var e = slides[i];
                if (e == slideshows[i].lastElementChild){
                    slideshows[i].firstElementChild.classList.add('current');
                } else {
                    e.nextElementSibling.classList.add('current')
                };
                e.classList.remove('current');
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
var id = startSlideshow();

for (var i=0;i<slideshows.length;i++){
    slideshows[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.classList.toggle('pause');
    });
}
```

```css
.slideshow {height:200px; margin-bottom:1px; width:300px;}
.slide {
    background-color:#555;
    height:200px;
    transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
}
.slide:nth-child(even) {background-color:#d14124;}
.slide.current {opacity:1;}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
    <article class="slide current">One</article>
    <article class="slide">Two</article>
    <article class="slide">Three</article>
    <article class="slide">Four</article>
    <article class="slide">Five</article>
</div>
 
<div class="slideshow">
    <article class="slide current">1</article>
    <article class="slide">2</article>
    <article class="slide">3</article>
    <article class="slide">4</article>
    <article class="slide">5</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current implementation, the quickest way is to check if the `pause` class is added and skip the animation if it is: `if($this.classList.contains('pause'))continue;` However, since all `current` items are handled with `document.querySelectorAll('.current')` inside each iteration of `slideShows`, you might want to remove the inner loop and use `$this.querySelector('.current')` to get the current item of that specific slide show:

```
var slideshows = document.querySelectorAll('.slideshow');
function startSlideshow() {
    return window.setInterval(function(){
        for (var i=0;i<slideshows.length;i++){
          var $this = slideshows[i];
          if($this.classList.contains('pause'))continue;
          var e  = $this.querySelector('.current');
          (e.nextElementSibling || $this.firstElementChild).classList.add('current');
          e.classList.remove('current');            
        }
    }, 1000);
}
var id = startSlideshow();

for (var i=0;i<slideshows.length;i++){
    slideshows[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.classList.toggle('pause');
    });
}
```

Another option is to have each slideshow contain its own timer, and start/stop that. However that could cause them to run out of sync with each other after a stop/start.

As an aside, instead of adding a pause class, you could also use objects, set a dataSet property or have the div add/remove itself from the `slideshows` array